# SQL Server 05\08: Grant Exec with special char in login

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Trying to run the command:

```
grant exec on GetPrograms to fp\ouruser_api
```

When I run it, I get the error message "incorrect syntax near \", but this is the login id stored in our database, how can I grant this user permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grant exec on GetPrograms to [fp\ouruser_api]

Answer (score 0):

Delimit unusual identifiers with []. Always.

Don't use them in system stored proc calls though:

```
CREATE USER [fp\ouruser_api] FROM LOGON [fp\ouruser_api];;
GRANT CONNECT TO [fp\ouruser_api];
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'foobar', 'fp\ouruser_api';
```

Speaking of which, best practice is to create roles and assign permission to the role. Add user to roles.
So continuing my example...

```
grant exec on GetPrograms to foobar;
```